# How to add element to an array?

Tags: arrays, logic

**Interview question**

Recently I was asked to write an program in any logic to add element to array

```
 $arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10);
```

Now we need to add `6` after `5`.

Condition are:

1) We cannot use `temp variable` and `new array` to store.

2) Cannot use in-build function.

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The size of an array can't be modified. If you want a bigger array you have to instantiate a new one.

A better solution would be to use an ArrayList which can grow as you need it. The method ArrayList.toArray( T[] a ) gives you back your array if you need it in this form.

Comment: Nope its not an answer which I am looking for

Comment: The length of an array is immutable in java. This means you can't change the size of an array once you have created it. If you initialised it with 2 elements, its length is 2. You can however use a different collection.

List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myList.add(5);
myList.add(7);
And with a wrapper method

public void addMember(Integer x) {
    myList.add(x);
};

Comment: without using in build function.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the existing array and assign it a value.
`$arr[] = 11`
this will create an index and will value will be part of array.

Comment: I need to add to it in particular position and shift the remaining.

Comment: You will get your answer here https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/4fc68250ddb66c000301c983

Comment: In given link they have used variable which is not allowed. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

a[a.length] = 'e';

// a is now ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

To do the latter, merge the arrays, without a function you can just loop thru the arrays, should pick the largest one to loop on. But yeah, as the comments state. There's usually not a good reason to do so.

Comment: I need to add to it in particular position and shift the remaining

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10);
foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
    if($v == 5){
        $arr[$k] = $v;
        $arr[$k+1]=6;
    }elseif($v > 5){
        $arr[$k+1]=$v;
    }else{
        $arr[$k] = $v;
    }
}
print_r($arr);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/aZci2)